# What proof of onward travel, if any, is required when entering Peru?

Tags: visas, peru, visas-on-arrival, proof-of-onward-travel

I'm planning a trip to Peru this summer, but I don't yet know where I'll go after I leave Peru.  The [US State Department web site](http://travel.state.gov/travel/cis_pa_tw/cis/cis_998.html) says that proof of onward travel is required when entering Peru:

> ENTRY / EXIT REQUIREMENTS: A valid passport is required to enter and depart Peru. **Tourists must also provide evidence of return or onward travel.**

However, if I visit the site of the Washington DC [Embassy of Peru](http://www.embassyofperu.org/), then follow their [Tourism](http://www.peru.travel/en/) link, the [FAQ](http://www.peru.travel/en/faq-fq-2) states, under **Was requires visa to enter Peru?[sic]**, mentions nothing of an onward travel requirement, in

> Visas are not necessary for citizens from most countries in the Americas and Western Europe. Citizens of Bolivia, Ecuador and Chile do not need either a passport or a visa to enter certain regions of Peru. Check with the Peruvian consulate in your country for further information. Addresses and telephone numbers are included in the website of the Peruvian Foreign Ministry: www.rree.gob.pe
>   Visitors entering Peru for tourism are granted a 90-day stay, which can be extended by the Immigration Office.
>   Travelers must bear a valid passport or safe-conduct pass issued by Peruvian immigration authorities.

When I visit the web site for the [Dallas Peruvian Consulate](http://www.consuladoperu.com/consulados/index.php?consulado=DALLAS), I don't find any mention of visa requirements at all.

What are the actual requirements when entering Peru on a U.S. passport? Do I need proof of onward travel, or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The US State Departments website may be outdated. When a discrepancy exists, I would go with the embassy information.

This may be simply luck but I have entered Peru nine times by air and twice by land and was never asked for any proof of onward travel. The last time was by air on December 23, 2012, so very recently.

Comment: I also suspect the State Department reflects "official" policy, which often differs drastically from enforced policy.

Comment: For clarification, are you traveling on a U.S. visa as well?

Comment: No visa is required for citizens of [North America (and other regions)](http://www.expatperu.com/etourist.php) since 2008. You get a tourist card on entry which you keep until you exit.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say a U.S. passport.

Comment: Mine is a Canadian passport but I used to go to Peru with a group made up mostly of of Americans annually. Unlike Bolivia, both Peru and Ecuador treat Americans and Canadians the same, well except they mostly accept *your* money :)